# web3-react does not appear to be exposing Ethers.js instance

Tags: react, web3-providers, ethers.js

I've configured the `web3-react` package in my project (set up with the React Truffle box) but I don't seem to be getting an ethers.js instance in the context.

According to the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-react), the `web3-react` context provides "`library`: An instantiated ethers.js or web3.js instance (or the low-level provider object)". It seems that I am getting the low-level provider object.

I set things up as follows (I have Ganache configured locally with `networkId` 13):

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const { InjectedConnector } = Connectors;
  const MetaMask = new InjectedConnector({ supportedNetworks: [1, 4, 13] });
  const connectors = { MetaMask };
  return (
    <Web3Provider connectors={connectors} libraryName={'ethers.js'}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/simple-storage' component={SimpleStorage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Web3Provider>
  );
}
```

**SimpleStorage.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useWeb3Context } from 'web3-react';
import SimpleStorageContract from './contracts/SimpleStorage.json'; // ABI

export default function SimpleStorage() {
  const context = useWeb3Context();
  const [storageValue, setStorageValue] = useState(0);
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => context.setFirstValidConnector(['MetaMask']), [context]);
  const { account, active, error, library, networkId } = context;

  if (!active && !error) return <div>loading</div>;
  if (error) return <div>error</div>;

  const { Contract, providers } = ethers;

  const instantiate = () => {
    const { networks, abi } = SimpleStorageContract;
    const { address } = networks[networkId];
    const provider = new providers.Web3Provider(library.provider);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const instance = new Contract(address, abi, signer);
    setContract(instance);
  };
...
```

Here is what I get from the context, which I believe is the MetaMask-injected web3 provider:

**`react3-web library`**

```
{
  "_isProvider": true,
  "_events": [],
  "_emitted": {
    "block": -2
  },
  "formatter": {
    "formats": {
      "transaction": {},
      "transactionRequest": {},
      "receiptLog": {},
      "receipt": {},
      "block": {},
      "blockWithTransactions": {},
      "filter": {},
      "filterLog": {}
    }
  },
  "anyNetwork": false,
  "_networkPromise": {},
  "_maxInternalBlockNumber": -1024,
  "_lastBlockNumber": -2,
  "_pollingInterval": 4000,
  "_fastQueryDate": 0,
  "connection": {
    "url": "metamask"
  },
  "_nextId": 42,
  "provider": {
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 3,
    "_maxListeners": 100,
    "isMetaMask": true,
    "_state": {
      "sentWarnings": {
        "enable": true,
        "experimentalMethods": false,
        "send": false,
        "events": {
          "chainIdChanged": false,
          "close": false,
          "data": false,
          "networkChanged": true,
          "notification": false
        },
        "autoRefresh": true,
        "publicConfigStore": false
      },
      "isConnected": true,
      "accounts": [
        "0x8cab72aad873e9450b10fa785df981986c3dea18"
      ],
      "isUnlocked": true
    },
    "_metamask": {},
    "selectedAddress": "0x8cab72aad873e9450b10fa785df981986c3dea18",
    "networkVersion": "13",
    "chainId": "0xd",
    "_publicConfigStore": {
      "_events": {
        "update": [
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      },
      "_eventsCount": 1,
      "_state": {
        "isUnlocked": true,
        "chainId": "0xd",
        "networkVersion": "13"
      }
    },
    "_rpcEngine": {
      "_events": {},
      "_eventsCount": 0,
      "_middleware": [
        null,
        null,
        null
      ]
    },
    "autoRefreshOnNetworkChange": false
  }
}
```

How can I get the instantiated Ethers.js from the context? As you can see I've imported ethers to interact with the contract but but doesn't that defeat the purpose of (presumably) having it available from the context?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but you could take a look at how web3-react is coupled with ethers.js in [uniswap-interface](https://github.com/uniswap/uniswap-interface).

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out, also will take a look at deploying to a testnet, e.g. whether using an Infura network connector changes anything.

Answer (score 3):

In fact with web3-react:

```
const provider = new providers.Web3Provider(library.provider);
```

is equal to:

```
const context = useWeb3React();
const { library } = context;
```

Then you can do everything that **provider** do using **library**